# Jenkins Running power-shell RDP on Windows Agent

Tags: powershell, jenkins, rdp, agent

Im trying to open an RDP file on a Windows agent.. just to get session opened nothing else.

also tried different variation..
p.s
the RDP.PS1 creating the RDP file and if i double click it its openning the connection

option 1 :

```
node('JenkinsWindows') {
 writeFile file: "session.txt", text: "${env.FILE}"
 powershell(". '.\\RDP.ps1'")
 powershell(returnStdout: true, script: """
   Start-Job -ScriptBlock '{cmd /c "mstsc.exe rdp.rdp"}' 
  """)
 sleep 5
```

option 2:
powershell script on the agent .

p.s the rdp.ps1 creating the rdp.rdp file and its works manually

Answer (score 1):

Script blocks `{ }` shouldn't be in quotes, and there's no real reason to launch `cmd` from powershell. Try something like this:

```
powershell(returnStdout: true, script: "Start-Job -ScriptBlock {start rdp.rdp}")
```

You probably don't need to run it as a job either, an even simpler version is:

```
powershell(returnStdout: true, script: "Start-Process rdp.rdp")
```

---

**Note:** You didn't show how you're creating the RDP file in your question, but be aware that untrusted/unsigned RDP connections may prompt the user before connecting. This prompt may not show up (but could stop your connection), depending on how Jenkins is running:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I used it like this (after a lot of tries). I don't understand why but it didn't work. Also no errors. What makes it hard.

I've installed a session recorder and this is working somehow:

```
writeFile file: "session.txt", text: "${env.FILE}"
powershell(". '.\\RDP.ps1'")
bat("start mstsc rdp.rdp")
```